# Prevent Delay() from firing

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$("#parahide").on("click", function () {
  $(this).dequeue().slideUp('400');
}).delay(6000).slideUp('400');
```

Here both the click() as well as delay() hides the div using slideup(). How can I prevent the second slideup() after delay() from firing, if the user has already clicked the para in 6 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.stop(true)` to clear the animation queue which will clear any pending animation actions including the delay and the slideup.

```
$("#parahide").on("click", function () {
    $(this).stop(true).slideUp('400');
}).delay(6000).slideUp('400');
```

I'm not quite sure why this is a problem at all because calling `.slideUp()` on something that is already hidden probably doesn't do anything visible.

Comment: yes but why the additional call if slideup has already been called in the click event. My logic is correct right?

Comment: @user1089173 - Why what additional call?  You asked how to stop the `.delay()` from firing and `.stop(true)` is how you clear it from the animation queue so it won't fire. It isn't easy to pick and choose which things you remove from the animation queue - removing some and leaving others - so it's better to just clear the queue and then add back whatever action you want.

Comment: No no I was answering your question "I'm not quite sure why this is a problem at all because calling .slideUp() on something that is already hidden probably doesn't do anything visible."